# How to supply value for HttpContext.Current when the OnItemSaving event is triggered via SPE?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have created a Powershell script that involves automatic assignment of page design to an item.
Below are the portions of codes I am using:

**Powershell code:**

[image: Sample of powershell script that assigns the page design id to the Page Design field]

**C-Sharp code**

[image: C-Sharp code of the OnItemSaving event of the Page Design]

My problem is that whenever I am going to end the editing (whenever I hit the OnItemSaving event), I am not getting any value for the **HttpContext.Current**; hence, my request is being returned.

I do not want to remove the checks for HttpContext.Current as I still want to validate whenever it's empty or not.

Comment: Is the HttpContext null on both clicking the save button and when executing via powershell?

Comment: Why do you need the validation?

Comment: Hi @HishaamNamooya, it's only null when executing via powershell

Comment: @Gatogordo actually the validation was added long time ago by a team member who only mentioned that it was a fix for something but I honestly couldn't track where it's applicable or when that validation is necessary. Since it's a pipeline event, I really can't afford simply removing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Sitecover Powershell ISE](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/interfaces/scripting): by default, the script executes as a background job. You can try to click on dropdown under *Execute* button and select "*Execute in http request context*"
[image]

Comment: Man that's cool! Didn't know that option exists! :)
By the way, I am actually triggering the powershell script via a scheduled task. Can I execute it the same way as clicking that "Execute in http request context" button?

Comment: https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/175586098ee47a9ce5a91eb4ec01502900f98b25/src/Spe/Integrations/Tasks/ExecuteScriptTask.cs

It looks like SPE executes scheduled tasks in the context of item inherited from /sitecore/templates/Modules/PowerShell Console/PowerShell Script.

I don't see an option how to re-configure it. But it should be possible to duplicate item /sitecore/system/tasks/Commands/PowerShellScriptCommand, change logic how powershell script is started by inheriting from Spe.Integrations.Tasks.ExecuteScriptTask and overriding how the session is configured.

Comment: Will try that one, thanks @Anton!